# Purpose of com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version

Tags: java, jackson-modules

I'm trying to understand the purpose of [com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Version.html) from Jackson core. Documentation says

> Object that encapsulates versioning information of a component. Version information includes not just version number but also optionally group and artifact ids of the component being versioned.

But this explanation looks trivial. It just says that keeps the version info, but does not says which effect has specifying a version or another. I only see examples like the following

```
SimpleModule module = 
  new SimpleModule("ModuleName", new Version(1, 0, 0, null, null, null));
```

In which a new module is added (e.g. to register a custom serializer/deserializer), but it is not clear the effect of the version.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

It offers a dynamic way for non-Jackson code to inspect version(s) of Jackson components: both core entities like `JsonFactory` and `ObjectMapper`, and extension modules. All official components generate this information so that at runtime other code can inspect version, if they are interested in that.

What this could be used for is:

- Diagnostics: for larger systems it may be good to verify version being used during runtime is actually what was planned (build/deploy systems may sometimes get complicated enough to have conflicts)
- Enforcing consistent set of components: extension modules may, for example, check version of `ObjectMapper` to ensure that version if at least certain minimum version.

But as to how it is used by Jackson: currently it is mostly offered as metadata for code outside Jackson. While it could be used by modules (and perhaps it will, for 3.0?), the only module I know that uses this information currently is Jackson Scala module which refuses to work with `jackson-databind` version that has older minor version (databind 2.5 with scala module 2.6, for example): this to reduce likelihood of "silent" errors, cases where class loading succeeds but there may be discrepancies in expected behavior.

Your custom module need not provide meaningful version number, although it is good practice to do so.
Jackson's `pom.xml`s include plug-in settings to generate class that returns maven version number. This is done by a template file like:

```
src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/PackageVersion.java.in
```

(in case of `jackson-databind`)

being processed with Maven version information, generating Java source class which is then compiled and used by `ObjectMapper` (et al).
(earlier, included `pom.xml` was read for same information but on some platforms (Android specifically) this had huge overhead when VM needed to keep resource files available).

Comment: tanks its work,  public static final Version VERSION = VersionUtil.parseVersion("2.5.1", "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-core");